# Setting the x property through effect does not work on target UI Component?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a Move effect that was working but now that I put it into a Parallel composition effect it no longer works. Here is the effect declaration:

```
    <s:Parallel id="slideToTheRightAnimation">
        <s:Move id="slideToTheRightMove" target="{myComponent}" xFrom="0" 
                    effectUpdate="trace('myComponent x=' + myComponent.x)"/>
    </s:Parallel>
```

Here is the component definition:

```
<comp:OptionsPalette id="myComponent" width="350" height="115" y="160"
                              layoutDirection="{LocaleManager.layoutDirection}"
                              visible="false"
                              requestPaletteClose="closeME()"
                              depth="-1">
    <comp:filters>
        <skins:StandardShadow/>
    </comp:filters>
</comp:OptionsPalette>
```

I'm setting the `xTo` property right before calling slideToTheRightAnimation play() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the cause. I had set the depth of the component to -1 to be below other components. When this is set the x property always returned `NaN`.

Setting the depth to 0 caused the Move effect to work again. Not sure why this is the case though. I thought you could set the depth to negative values and the compiler did not complain and the component displayed properly (though it did not move or animate). Maybe I'm thinking of AS2 for the depth issue???